# Visual Studio Online doesn't build my application, can I cannot clone the repository

Tags: git, azure-devops

I've been using Visual Studio Online to manage my builds, and it seems to have been fine up until recently. I think someone has changed something, but I can't seem to see what.

Now I can't seem to clone my repository, or run a build.

It seems to be some form of authentication problem. But I haven't been able to establish why the permissions seem correct for each of the users (including myself).

When I try to build the code that is on the solution already I get a pop up with this;

> 500: No security token was found for artifact vstfs:///Build/Build/14 using extension Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.BuildTaskHubExtension.
>   TFS.WebApi.Exception: No security token was found for artifact vstfs:///Build/Build/14 using extension Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.Server.BuildTaskHubExtension.
>       at k (https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:375)
>       at https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:2964
>       at d (https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:635)
>       at https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/corejs?v=8oe2VxmtIRMt5sf9uSOR8Ipd_3B9HcCaQWsEjeX4ZOs1:40:2897
>       at l (https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8122)
>       at https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:8348
>       at t.when (https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:3780)
>       at t.u.promiseDispatch (https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:2824)
>       at https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:1649
>       at MessagePort.t (https://xxxx/_static/tfs/20150901T200043/_scripts/TFS/min/q.js:27:5773)

When I try to clone the repository (using SmartGit or even Sourcetree) it just hangs. And I can't seem to push or pull using the original local repositories.

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you open the Git shell and try looking there?  What happens when you type `git status` from the root of your project directory?

Comment: @Nav, 1). How about you create a new build definition to queue a new build? 2). How about your other team members? Do they get the same error? 3). Do you try to push/pull large projects which cause SmartGit or Sourcetree hang?

Comment: Tried Git status locally, apparently no issues there, @vicky, I've tried a new build definition that didn't work either, I tried another build server and that worked. Luckily er're able to just switch without much of a problem. As much as I'd love to resolve the issues. It's not worth the issues.

Comment: Have exact same issue, pulling hairs